# I can't target one of two inline icons

Tags: html, css, icons, target

I’m working on my footer and I have some contact info floating to the right and the text is aligned right.

Below that I wanted to put social media links. I wanted “Follow me at:” then icons for Facebook and Instagram. I gave these icons as well as others in my footer the class “icon”. In my css I targeted them and gave them color, pseudo classes, size, etc. For some unknown reason, the first icon isn’t being targeted. I even copied and pasted the code for the second over the first one and it’s still no targeted. Is there a rule I’m missing? I haven’t messed with spans much, so I may be screwing that up. I wanted it inline, unlike the other contact where the small icons sit in their own block above the text. That was a happy mistake. I like it.

Anyway, here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="soc-media">

<span>Follow EmJ Pilates on:</span>

<span class='icon'><a href='http://facebook.com'><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a></span>

<span class='icon'><a href='https://instragram.com'><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></span>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon{
color: goldenrod;
font-size: 200%;
}
.icon a:link{
color: goldenrod;
}
.icon a:hover{
color: #bbbbbb;
}
```

And here’s a link to the screen shot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2d2r0uzyh6yyjtd/Screenshot%202015-07-24%2011.39.20.png?dl=0

Comment: Where are your call to the icons?

Comment: please replicate same issue in fiddlejs and send the url

Comment: `color` assigned to `a` will only apply to text, here however I can only assume `fa fa-facebook-square` returns an image. You can't change the color of an image using css. Notice by adding a string into the `<a> </a>` tags your css is applied as can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/q50Lfq64/

Comment: OK. Sorry for the sloppy post and thanks for your patience! I'm a noob!

When I just put in the html and css involved... both the facebook and instagram icons turn yellow and are properly targeted. But when I put all the code it, it doesn't work. Here's the jfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/digi57/965tLnL2/

Comment: I think I just needed to change the <span> to <div> then display them as inline-block.